# Heat kernel upper bounds on compact manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation

I am interested in Gaussian-type upper bounds for the heat kernel on forms in a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ of dimension $n$.  My understanding is that the Sobolev embedding $H^1\hookrightarrow L^{2n/(n-2)}$ holds for compact manifolds, and so there is a bound of the form
$$
p(t,x,y) \leq C t^{-n/2} \exp( - \frac{d^2(x,y)}{Ct}),
$$
where $p(t,x,y)$ is the heat kernel.

I am curious about the situation for differential forms (so, the heat kernel for the Hodge laplacian).  In this case, the heat kernel $p(t,x,y)$ is a tensor, and I imagine that there is an inequality
$$
|p(t,x,y)| \leq C t^{-n/2} \exp( - \frac{d^2(x,y)}{Ct}).
$$

However, the only references I can easily find treat the seemingly more difficult case of a non-compact Riemannian manifold.  Is there a good reference for the above inequality (if it is true!)?

Comment: "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators" by Berline and Getzler is the standard reference. You can also have a look at "Laplacian on Riemannian Manifolds"

Comment: Great, thanks.  I don't have access to the former book, but I have started to look at the latter.  I suppose the point is that the estimate I want is implied by the existence of a parametrix?  I suppose that far from the diagonal something else needs to be done..

Comment: Actually if you are away from the diagonal, the inequality can be managed since you are on a compact manifold. You only have to prove the inequality on a neighbourhood of the diagonal since that is where the RHS has some kind of a singularity. If you want to use PDE methods, you can look at  "John Roe - Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic methods-Chapman and Hall CRC (1999) ". He uses Dulhamel's principle to get the asymptotic expansion from which your inequality follows.

Comment: Thank you so much, these references are very helpful.

Comment: Let me add a sketch for posterity (now that I've digested Soumik's comment more).  The point is that the parametrix construction can be used to give a series expansion for the (exact) heat kernel, which is valid on the entire manifold but only for short times.  This series expansion is based on repeated convolutions of functions involving the parametrix.  This means that Gaussian-type upper bound I want can be proven for each term in the series expansion, once it is known for the parametrix.  I have found Patodi's paper "Curvature and the Eigenforms of the Laplacian" to be especially helpful.